# Use two Databases in one Bundle, one with orm and one without, but with entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.6

I'm currently developing an application in Symfony2.6 (first time using it) which basically is an new management system of an existing database of objects.
While the management (users, roles, routes etc) uses a new orm database, the objects are stored in an seperated database.

The object database also has a read only flag on some tables and gets modified by external staff, so an ORM on this database would be a bad idea.

But: I still want to have an (aggregated) entity of these objects which I can query and populate, also with writing back to specific tables and binding to forms.
Is there any best practice for achieving this?

EDIT: Essentially I want to have this:

Table1:

> col11 col12 col13 col14

Table2:

> col21 col22 col23 col24

Now I only want an object composed of col11, col14, col22, col24. 
How do I do this and how is it possible to populate and update via entity manager?

Comment: [How to generate entities based on an existing database](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exactly what I need. For example, I need an entity existing out of values from multiple tables.

Comment: You mean [Inheritance Mapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)?

Comment: I guess kind of. Please see my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice - to use two separate entity managers for each connection and enjoy all the benefits from ORM;-)

Comment: I'm already using two entity managers for reach database connection in one bundle. But still, I'm currently not sure how to implement aggregated entities.

Comment: What do you mean by aggregated entities?

Comment: The object database has about 10-15 tables (currently), but the representation on the website only needs 1-2 values per table. I want to aggregate these values in specific entities.

Comment: you can create entities with only fields you need

Comment: But I need entitites with fields from different source tables, aggregated into one object. Please see my edit above.